# How to scroll to an element in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, focus

I have done the following code in JavaScript to put focus on the particular element (branch1 is a  element),

```
document.location.href="#branch1";
```

But as I am also using jQuery in my web app, so I want to do the above code in jQuery. I have tried but don't know why its not working,

```
$("#branch1").focus();
```

The above jquery (focus()) code is not working for div, whereas If i am trying the same code with textbox, then its working,

Please tell me, how can I put focus on a div elemnt using jQuery?

Thanks!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Check [jQuery.ScrollTo](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo), I think that's the behavior that you want, check the [demo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/).

Comment: This answer pops up first Google. As of the new jQuery renovations, the new, correct URL is http://plugins.jquery.com/scrollto/

Comment: Even that address is outdated now. Author's Github repo is at https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo

Comment: Link out of date and not really jQuery,  but a jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 119):

For my problem this code worked, I had to navigate to an anchor tag on page load :

```
$(window).scrollTop($('a#captchaAnchor').position().top);
```

For that matter you can use this on any element, not just an anchor tag.

Comment: Instead of "$(this).scrollTop" you should use "$(window).scrollTop". The first only workings when "this" happens to be the same as "window".

Answer (score 52):

Like @user293153 I only just discovered this question and it didn't seem to be answered correctly.

His answer was best. But you can also animate to the element as well.

```
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $("#some_element").offset().top }, 500);
```

Comment: if you are using it inside a .live('click') and you notice the window jumps to the top of the page, add a "return false" as the last statement, it solves the problem for IE and Chrome :D

Comment: awesome. it doesnt' need a plugin.

Comment: Note that though it seems "html" would be unneeded in the selector, Firefox won't do the scroll without it. So $('html, body') works, $('body') does not (FF only, in IE and Chrome it works fine).

Answer (score 40):

You can extend jQuery functionalities like this:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
scrollToMe: function () {
    var x = jQuery(this).offset().top - 100;
    jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop: x}, 500);
}});
```

and then:

```
$('...').scrollToMe();
```

easy ;-)

Comment: That's the nicest solution, I think. Just add it once, and then forget about it... :-)

Comment: Very nice solution. This type of solution will go beyond the OP question and abbreviate a bunch of my code.

Comment: @Oudin I know this is slow to respond, but replace `'html,body'` with `'.scrollable-container'` and then add `scrollable-container' to the list of classes on your div. You could also add a parameter to `scrollToMe` which takes any specific selector you want to be the parent instead.

Comment: thanks thats an excellent answer. I didnt need the animation, so I just did ```scrollToMe: function () {
    var x = jQuery(this).offset().top - 100;
    $('html').scrollTop(x);
}});
```

Comment: Thanks, well done.  I extended this to handle scrolling objects in a scrolling window.   jQuery.fn.extend({
  scrollToMe: function (e) {
   if (typeof(e)=='undefined'){
    e='html,body';
   }
   var y = jQuery(this).offset().top;
   jQuery(e).animate({scrollTop: y}, 500);
  }
 });

Comment: this is the best solution

Answer (score 4):

**Check out [jquery-scrollintoview](https://github.com/litera/jquery-scrollintoview).**

ScrollTo is fine, but oftentimes you just want to make sure a UI element is visible, not necessarily at the top. ScrollTo doesn't help you with this. From scrollintoview's README:

> #### How does this plugin solve the user experience issue
>
> This plugin scrolls a particular element into view similar to browser
>   built-in functionality (DOM's scrollIntoView() function), but works
>   differently (and arguably more user friendly):
>
> - it only scrolls to element when element is actually out of view; if element is in view (anywhere in visible document area), no scrolling
>     will be performed;
> - it scrolls using animation effects; when scrolling is performed users know exactly they're not redirected anywhere, but actually see
>     that they're simply moved somewhere else within the same page (as well
>     as in which direction they moved);
> - there's always the smallest amount of scrolling being applied; when element is above the visible document area it will be scrolled to the
>     top of visible area; when element is below the visible are it will be
>     scrolled to the bottom of visible area; this is the most consistent
>     way of scrolling - when scrolling would always be to top it sometimes
>     couldn't scroll an element to top when it was close to the bottom of
>     scrollable container (thus scrolling would be unpredictable);
> - when element's size exceeds the size of visible document area its top-left corner is the one that will be scrolled to;

Answer (score 4):

Use

> $(window).scrollTop()

It'll scroll the window to the item.

```
 var scrollPos =  $("#branch1").offset().top;
 $(window).scrollTop(scrollPos);
```

Comment: Please don't add the [same answer to multiple questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions). Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates, once you earn enough reputation. If it is not a duplicate, [edit] the answer and tailor the post to the question.

Answer (score 4):

If you're simply trying to scroll to the specified element, you can use the [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) method of the Element.
Here's an example :

```
$target.get(0).scrollIntoView();
```

Comment: Thank you! Completely solved my issue. I've also added {behavior: "smooth"} as argument to scroll smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for an "anchor" given the example you have.

```
<a href="#jump">This link will jump to the anchor named jump</a>
<a name="jump">This is where the link will jump to</a>
```

The focus jQuery method does something different from what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Ya I'm trying to achieve the same anchoring task. Ok, if the focus can't do it, is there any other method in jquery which can do this?

Answer (score 0):

For the focus() function to work on the  element the div needs to have a tabindex attribute. This is probably not done by default on this type of element as it is not an input field. You can add a tabindex for example at -1 to prevent users who use tab to focus on it. If you use a positive tabindex users will be able to use tab to focus on the div element.

Here an example: http://jsfiddle.net/klodder/gFPQL/

However tabindex is not supported in Safari.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want to try this simple one

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".to-branch1").click(function() {
     $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: $("#branch1").offset().top
     }, 1500);
   });
});
```