# How do I get an element to scroll into view, using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML document with images in a grid format using `<ul><li><img...`. The browser window has both vertical & horizontal scrolling.

**Question:** 
When I click on an image `<img>`, how then do I get the whole document to scroll to a position where the image I just clicked on is `top:20px; left:20px` ?

I've had a browse on here for similar posts...although I'm quite new to JavaScript, and want to understand how this is achieved for myself.

Comment: Duplicate of: [How to scroll to an element in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500336)

Answer (score 208, accepted):

Since you want to know how it works, I'll explain it step-by-step.

First you want to bind a function as the image's click handler:

```
$('#someImage').click(function () {
    // Code to do scrolling happens here
});
```

That will apply the click handler to an image with `id="someImage"`. If you want to do this to *all* images, replace `'#someImage'` with `'img'`.

Now for the actual scrolling code:

1. Get the image offsets (relative to the document):

   ```
   var offset = $(this).offset(); // Contains .top and .left
   ```
2. Subtract 20 from `top` and `left`:

   ```
   offset.left -= 20;
   offset.top -= 20;
   ```
3. Now animate the scroll-top and scroll-left CSS properties of `<body>` and `<html>`:

   ```
   $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: offset.top,
       scrollLeft: offset.left
   });
   ```

Comment: This only works for simple layouts. It does not handle all cases the way the W3C `.scrollIntoView` method does when elements are nested within multiple overflowing containers.

Comment: why to reinvent the wheel? `Element.scrollIntoView()`:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Comment: @Serge because it's a working draft that hasn't been implemented in all browsers

Comment: @JohnSmith please read attentively the link I posted, the "Browser Compatibility" section, you will see there is no browser do not support the `scrollIntoView`

Comment: @Serge Sorry about that, I didn't realize, there was also scrollIntoViewOption (which is the one that is not supported wide enough). I guess it's good enough.

Comment: @serge I read attentively and it clearly says this is experimental and to expect behavior to change in the future. Hard to use this in production confidently.

Answer (score 446):

There's a DOM method called [`scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollIntoView), which is supported by all major browsers, that will align an element with the top/left of the viewport (or as close as possible).

```
$("#myImage")[0].scrollIntoView();
```

On supported browsers, you can provide options:

```
$("#myImage")[0].scrollIntoView({
    behavior: "smooth", // or "auto" or "instant"
    block: "start" // or "end"
});
```

Alternatively, if all the elements have unique IDs, you can just change the `hash` property of the [`location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) object for back/forward button support:

```
$(document).delegate("img", function (e) {
    if (e.target.id)
        window.location.hash = e.target.id;
});
```

After that, just adjust the `scrollTop`/`scrollLeft` properties by -20:

```
document.body.scrollLeft -= 20;
document.body.scrollTop -= 20;
```

Comment: Thank you! 5 other SO articles and you nailed it perfectly. My use case was a container in a bootstrap dialog that need to scroll into view.

Comment: As a note: `$("#myImage")[0].scrollIntoView(false);` will align the element on the bottom of the window.

Comment: Beware: the "smooth" behavior isn't widely supported, and `scrollIntoView` can be a confusing experience for users without some sort of animation.

Comment: scrollIntoView doesn't work on older IE. see http://caniuse.com/#feat=scrollintoview

Comment: @JohnHenckel: that's incorrect, even IE 5.5 had `scrollIntoView` with the boolean parameter.  I'll try and send a pull request for caniuse.com later.

Comment: Note: Using Chrome, I couldn't scroll `<td>` elements into view, instead had to scroll their parent (`<tr>`) and it worked.

Comment: This method, on nested `li` tags, was causing lateral scrolling, when I just want vertical scrolling.  Adjusting `scrollLeft` after the fact seems to negate the scroll entirely.  With the `animate` approach, you can specify just `scrollTop` or `scrollLeft` depending on the direction of scrolling you want.

Comment: Great that you added `[0]` after the JQuery object, that was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 21):

Simplest solution I have seen

```
var offset = $("#target-element").offset();
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: offset.top,
    scrollLeft: offset.left
}, 1000);
```

[Tutorial Here](https://www.abeautifulsite.net/smoothly-scroll-to-an-element-without-a-jquery-plugin-2)

Comment: At the risk of making it less simple, I edited this to support horizontal scrolling as well.

Answer (score 8):

There are methods to scroll element directly into the view, but if you want to scroll to a point relative from an element, you have to do it manually:

Inside the click handler, get the position of the element relative to the document, subtract `20` and use [`window.scrollTo`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Window.scrollTo):

```
var pos = $(this).offset();
var top = pos.top - 20;
var left = pos.left - 20;
window.scrollTo((left < 0 ? 0 : left), (top < 0 ? 0 : top));
```

Comment: Only one with worked for me with the webpage I have. I wanted my element centered so I changed the top & left assignments to `var top = pos.top - window.innerHeight / 2; var left = pos.left  - window.innerWidth / 2;`

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at the [jQuery.scrollTo](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo) plugin. Here's a [demo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/).

This plugin has a lot of options that go beyond what [native scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollIntoView) offers you. For instance, you can set the scrolling to be smooth, and then set a callback for when the scrolling finishes.

You can also have a look at [all the JQuery plugins tagged with "scroll"](https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/scroll/).

Comment: I was getting different offsets/positions in every browser in my case, and this plugin helped fixed it for me! thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Here's a quick jQuery plugin to map the built in browser functionality nicely:

```
$.fn.ensureVisible = function () { $(this).each(function () { $(this)[0].scrollIntoView(); }); };

...

$('.my-elements').ensureVisible();
```

Answer (score 4):

After trial and error I came up with this function, works with iframe too.

```
function bringElIntoView(el) {    
    var elOffset = el.offset();
    var $window = $(window);
    var windowScrollBottom = $window.scrollTop() + $window.height();
    var scrollToPos = -1;
    if (elOffset.top < $window.scrollTop()) // element is hidden in the top
        scrollToPos = elOffset.top;
    else if (elOffset.top + el.height() > windowScrollBottom) // element is hidden in the bottom
        scrollToPos = $window.scrollTop() + (elOffset.top + el.height() - windowScrollBottom);
    if (scrollToPos !== -1)
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: scrollToPos });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

My UI has a vertical scrolling list of thumbs within a thumbbar
The goal was to make the current thumb right in the center of the thumbbar.
I started from the approved answer, but found that there were a few tweaks to truly center the current thumb.  hope this helps someone else.

markup:

```
<ul id='thumbbar'>
    <li id='thumbbar-123'></li>
    <li id='thumbbar-124'></li>
    <li id='thumbbar-125'></li>
</ul>
```

jquery:

```
// scroll the current thumb bar thumb into view
heightbar   = $('#thumbbar').height();
heightthumb = $('#thumbbar-' + pageid).height();
offsetbar   = $('#thumbbar').scrollTop();


$('#thumbbar').animate({
    scrollTop: offsetthumb.top - heightbar / 2 - offsetbar - 20
});
```

Comment: I think you need to add in: offsetthumb = $('#thumbbar-' + pageid).offset(); And also replace the object with:     scrollTop: offsetthumb.top - heightbar / 2 - heightthumb / 2 + offsetbar

Answer (score 2):

Just a tip. Works on firefox only

[Element.scrollIntoView();](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: This is working for all browsers with boolean parameter or no parameters at all. Only more advanced object parameter is less supported.

Comment: according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView there is general lack of browser support for this

Comment: It's now well enough supported only Opera Mini: https://caniuse.com/#search=scrollIntoView

Comment: There's a number of very lightweight polyfills out there for it.

Answer (score 1):

After trying to find a solution that handled every circumstance (options for animating the scroll, padding around the object once it scrolls into view, works even in obscure circumstances such as in an iframe), I finally ended up writing my own solution to this. Since it seems to work when many other solutions failed, I thought I'd share it:

```
function scrollIntoViewIfNeeded($target, options) {

    var options = options ? options : {},
    $win = $($target[0].ownerDocument.defaultView), //get the window object of the $target, don't use "window" because the element could possibly be in a different iframe than the one calling the function
    $container = options.$container ? options.$container : $win,        
    padding = options.padding ? options.padding : 20,
    elemTop = $target.offset().top,
    elemHeight = $target.outerHeight(),
    containerTop = $container.scrollTop(),
    //Everything past this point is used only to get the container's visible height, which is needed to do this accurately
    containerHeight = $container.outerHeight(),
    winTop = $win.scrollTop(),
    winBot = winTop + $win.height(),
    containerVisibleTop = containerTop < winTop ? winTop : containerTop,
    containerVisibleBottom = containerTop + containerHeight > winBot ? winBot : containerTop + containerHeight,
    containerVisibleHeight = containerVisibleBottom - containerVisibleTop;

    if (elemTop < containerTop) {
        //scroll up
        if (options.instant) {
            $container.scrollTop(elemTop - padding);
        } else {
            $container.animate({scrollTop: elemTop - padding}, options.animationOptions);
        }
    } else if (elemTop + elemHeight > containerTop + containerVisibleHeight) {
        //scroll down
        if (options.instant) {
            $container.scrollTop(elemTop + elemHeight - containerVisibleHeight + padding);
        } else {
            $container.animate({scrollTop: elemTop + elemHeight - containerVisibleHeight + padding}, options.animationOptions);
        }
    }
}
```

`$target` is a jQuery object containing the object you wish to scroll into view if needed.

`options` (optional) can contain the following options passed in an object:

`options.$container` - a jQuery object pointing to the containing element of $target (in other words, the element in the dom with the scrollbars). Defaults to the window that contains the $target element and is smart enough to select an iframe window. Remember to include the $ in the property name.

`options.padding` - the padding in pixels to add above or below the object when it is scrolled into view. This way it is not right against the edge of the window. Defaults to 20.

`options.instant` - if set to true, jQuery animate will not be used and the scroll will instantly pop to the correct location. Defaults to false.

`options.animationOptions` - any jQuery options you wish to pass to the jQuery animate function (see http://api.jquery.com/animate/). With this, you can change the duration of the animation or have a callback function executed when the scrolling is complete. This only works if `options.instant` is set to false. If you need to have an instant animation but with a callback, set `options.animationOptions.duration = 0` instead of using `options.instant = true`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple 2 steps for scrolling down to end or bottom.

Step1: get the full height of scrollable(conversation) div.

Step2: apply scrollTop on that scrollable(conversation) div using the value 
        obtained in step1.

```
var fullHeight = $('#conversation')[0].scrollHeight;

$('#conversation').scrollTop(fullHeight);
```

Above steps must be applied for every append on the conversation div.