# Automatic scroll on div on li element overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm trying to apply automatic scroll in div. I have a list of element under fixed height div now i want when i press key down after 3rd highlight li element (i.e Compt0005) div scroll automatically. can any body solve it..

`Demo`:- [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/subhash9/6aj7t/11/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code sets the scrollTop property of the div exactly via [.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getBoundingClientRect) method:

```js
$(function () {
    var liPossition = 0;
    var items = $("#ulSearch li");
    var divSearchContent = $("#divSearchContent");
    divSearchContent.hide();
    $("#txtSearch").keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) { // if enter pressed
            $("#txtSearch").val(items.eq(liPossition).text());
            divSearchContent.hide();
            return;
        }
        if (e.keyCode != 38 && e.keyCode != 40) { // // if not up or down arrow
            return;
        }
        divSearchContent.show();
        items.eq(liPossition).css("background-color", "");
        if (e.keyCode == 40 && liPossition < items.length - 1) { // down arrow key code
            liPossition++;
        }
        if (e.keyCode == 38 && liPossition > 0) { // up arrow key code
            liPossition--;
        }
        items.eq(liPossition).css("background-color", "red");//[0].scrollIntoView(); return;
        var b1 = divSearchContent[0].getBoundingClientRect();
        var b2 = items.eq(liPossition)[0].getBoundingClientRect();
        if (b1.top>b2.top) {
            divSearchContent.scrollTop( divSearchContent.scrollTop()-b1.top+b2.top );
        }
        else if (b1.bottom<b2.bottom) {
            divSearchContent.scrollTop( divSearchContent.scrollTop()-b1.bottom+b2.bottom );
        }
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6aj7t/23/)

Comment: Nice 1 this answer is work better for me

Comment: can you also reset process when click rather than text box.

Comment: It show error in my page "Cannot call method 'getBoundingClientRect' of undefined "

Comment: Hello Ajay, maybe something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/6aj7t/19/ http://jsfiddle.net/6aj7t/19/show Used also `.focus()` function ;-)

Comment: alternatively you can add/remove the class instead of changing the background: http://jsfiddle.net/6aj7t/20/

Comment: It is show error on my code on this line "var b1 = divSearchContent[0].getBoundingClientRect();" Err="Cannot call method 'getBoundingClientRect' of undefined "

Comment: it show the content of divSearchContent

Comment: No, i run this code in chrome

Comment: there are some error on this code... 1) first time when key down second li element highlight rather than first 2) last element not shown after scrolling

Answer (score 3):

change every occurence of

```
$("#ulSearch li:eq(" + liPossition + ")").css("background-color", "red")
```

to

```
 $("#ulSearch li:eq(" + liPossition + ")").css("background-color", "red")[0].scrollIntoView();
```

Comment: It's work fine but it scroll on every li but i want scroll after 3rd element

Comment: in that case it wont be simple, you have to check if he element is in the view or not, and then have to scroll.

Comment: may be you want to check this also - [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884839/how-do-i-get-a-element-to-scroll-into-view-using-jquery]