# How can I scroll to a certain div onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vb.net

I have this function

```
    function first_scroll() {
        document.getElementById('insert').scrollIntoView();
    }
```

and this button

```
Button ID="finish" runat="server" Text="Finalize" OnClientClick="first_scroll()"
```

This button runs some code and I want the page to scroll after running this code. Right now, this scrolls down to the speicific div for less than a second and then after postback, it starts up in the top again.

To solve this, I tried using

```
<% Page MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" %>
```

However, this had no effect.
So, how do I make the page scroll after running some code?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First you want to bind a function as the image's click handler:

```
$('#someImage').click(function () {
    // Code to do scrolling happens here
});
```

That will apply the click handler to an image with `id="someImage"`. If you want to do this to *all* images, replace `'#someImage'` with `'img'`.

Now for the actual scrolling code:

1. Get the image offsets (relative to the document):

   ```
   var offset = $(this).offset(); // Contains .top and .left
   ```
2. Subtract 20 from `top` and `left`:

   ```
   offset.left -= 20;
   offset.top -= 20;
   ```
3. Now animate the scroll-top and scroll-left CSS properties of `<body>` and `<html>`:

   ```
   $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: offset.top,
       scrollLeft: offset.left
   });
   ```

Also, have a look at the [jQuery.scrollTo](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) plugin.

Here's a [demo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/).

This is a repeating question [from this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884839/how-do-i-get-a-element-to-scroll-into-view-using-jquery/4884928#4884928).

Comment: Why 20? Seems arbitrary.

Comment: @Simon, yes that's arbitrary and can have different value for different set of codes.

Comment: @baba, I've used the jQuery.ScrollTo plugin in a few places and worked out fine for me. Did you refer to the demo? Any good?