# Embedded Google calendar : how to set range of hours to display?

Tags: iframe, google-api, google-calendar-api

Given the following embedding code:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?
title=2014 PLIDAM International Symposium (Paris)&
dates=20140611/20140615&
mode=WEEK&amp;
showNav=1&amp;
showDate=1&amp;
showPrint=1&amp;
showTabs=1&amp;
showCalendars=0&amp;
showTz=1;
height=600&amp;
wkst=2&amp;
bgcolor=%23666666&amp;
src=vdfmfbp0msroletduigs2qtkoc%40group.calendar.google.com&amp;
color=%232952A3&amp;
ctz=Europe%2FParis" 
style=" border:solid 1px #777 " width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

**Is there a parameter to set the hours to display/focus_on from 09:00 to 18:00 (6pm), aka the working hours ?** Same for days, is there someways to just display/focus_on the rights 4 days only.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/F7j9k/1/)

Comment: Still no solution? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: I'm looking for this response too.

Comment: Same here. There must be a way to do this, yeah?

Comment: Can you be a little more elaborative ?

Answer (score 3):

There doesn't appear to be a way to do this through the API, currently. I would use javascript/jQuery to remove the elements you don't want to show in the DOM after the iframe has finished loading.

So, you could delete the Wednesday column, if you know the column index, by something like this:

```
$("tr").each(function() {
    $(this).filter("td:eq(3)").remove();
});
```

You can also scroll a specific div into view:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4884904/5129424

```
$("#myImage")[0].scrollIntoView();
```