How to scroll to specific element using jquery?
How to scroll on specific element using jquery?
What I've tried is this
$("html,body").animate({scrollTop: $(".highlights").offset().top - $("html,body").offset().top + $("html,body").scrollTop(), scrollLeft: 0},300);

It works, but it cannot freely scroll up and down. So I am looking for something that scrolls on a specific element and still allows the user to continue scrolling up or down as usual.

Does this answer your question? How to scroll to specific item using jQuery?

If you want to scroll a specific element into view you can use this function .scrollIntoView().
Referencing this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4884904/19097807
