# Animate scroll to next/prev post

Tags: jquery

How can I create two buttons ("next" and "prev") that will scroll the browser to the article's title?

```
<div id="cycle-posts">
    <a id="next" href="#next"></a>
    <a id="prev" href="#prev"></a>
</div>

<article>My first post</article>
<article>My second post</article>
<article>My third post</article>
<article>My fourth post</article>
```

If it's relevant: after the first few, my articles are loaded in using "infinite scroll".

This is what I got so far, but it's not even close:

```
$('#cycle-posts a').bind('click', function (e) {
    $articles = $('article');
    e.preventDefault();
    var totalArticles = $articles.length;


    if ($(this).attr("id") == "next") {
        new_index = ++current_index;
    } else if ($(this).attr("id") == "prev") {
        new_index = --current_index;
    }

    if (new_index > totalArticles) {
        new_index = 0;
    }   

    $articles.removeClass('current').eq(new_index).addClass('current');

    console.log(new_index+' / '+totalArticles);

    // now scroll offset, find offset based on .current?

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the handler we remove the `current` class to the element that it actually has it and then we select the next (or previous) element and we add the `current` class to it (only if it's not the first or last element).

Then we scroll to that element, animating `scrollTop`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500336/how-to-scroll-to-an-element-in-jquery).

```
(function() {
    var scrollTo = function(element) {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: element.offset().top
        }, 500);
    }
    $('#next').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $current = $('#container > .current');
        if ($current.index() != $('#container > div').length - 1) {
            $current.removeClass('current').next().addClass('current');
            scrollTo($current.next());
        }
    });
    $('#prev').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $current = $('#container > .current');
        if (!$current.index() == 0) {
            $current.removeClass('current').prev().addClass('current');
            scrollTo($current.prev());
        }
    });
})();
```

[You have a fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/KkecC/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to calculate the current index on every single click, I find it's much better to use a function to produce both the forward and back click handlers that also stores the index as a local.  This way both can reference the index and it doesn't have to be calculated on the fly.

Try the following

```
(function() { 
  var index = 0;
  $('article:first').addClass('current');
  var moveOne = function (forward) {
    var articles = $('article');
    articles.eq(index).removeClass('current');
    if (forward) {
      index++;
      if (index === articles.length) {
        index = 0;
      }
    } else { 
      index--;
      if (index < 0) {
        index = articles.length - 1;
      }
    }
    articles.eq(index).addClass('current');
  }

  $('#next').click(function () { moveOne(true); });
  $('#prev').click(function () { moveOne(false); });

})();
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5f74F/