# How to focus a particular portion of a web page after redirect

Tags: javascript, html

i want to focus a particular portion of a web page after redirecting the page(redirected page=again original page) for that how to write a code using javascript

```
<a href="http://......" />
<script type="text/javascript">


</script>
```

Comment: Maybe use anchores? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13735912/anchor-jumping-by-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You should use id'd anchors and fragment identifiers.

Any URL can contain fragment identifiers like **#section1** in the example below.

http://www.example.com/mypage.html#section1

That would cause the page to scroll this anchor into view:

<a id="section1">Section 1</a>

Here's a live example of that behavior:

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.1.1

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried combining a href to take you to another page with the href to take you to another egment within the same page?  For example -

```
<a href="http://targetsite.com/targetpage.html#target-element">Link text</a>
```

The above will take you to the target page http://targetsite.com/targetpage.html and the element identified using `id = "target-element"`.

Is this what you are trying to do?