# HTML anchor in AS3

Tags: html, actionscript-3, flash

I have an HTML page with a Flash animation inside of it.
In my page, I created some anchors like this example :

```
<a id="p1"><h1>Title 1</h1>
```

My goal is to access to this anchor with AS3 from a button, so I wrote this :

```
function re(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest("text.html/#p1"),"_parent"
    );
}
```

It works, **however it removes the swf file from the page.** Maybe I found the issue, after clicking to the button, I got the HTML link *without* the #p1.

Do you have a way to get this link with the anchor in AS3 ?

In that case I think it would scroll the page until the anchor without removing the swf file...

Comment: Try using AS3's `externalInterface` to run a JS function in your page, where function should do the `#p1` scroll. _It might just work..._

Comment: @VC.One Thanks for the help, but what should I write in JS for a scroll function ?  Because I don't call any anchors in HTML, only in AS3...Sorry, I'm a bit inexperienced with JS.

Comment: http://help.typepad.com/anchor-tags.html then either navigateToURL(new URLRequest("#p1"),"_parent"); or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13735912/anchor-jumping-by-using-javascript