# Scroll to anchor on refresh or on manual URL change

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, anchor

I implemented the code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49328627/1735672), enabling the scroll to anchor while navigating using the router.

But I noticed that on a refresh or manual navigation (by manipulating the URL), the page does not scroll to anchor as expected.

I can add this code to all pages, and it is going to work:

```
mounted() {
    console.log('Location:', location.hash); //returns '#options'
    console.log('Route:', this.$route.hash); //returns '#options'

    if (location.hash)
        this.$nextTick().then(() => this.$scrollTo(location.hash, 700));
}
```

**Is there any global way to set this code, without having to set the code in every page?**

I've tried to set that on the `App.vue` file, the `location.hash` prop returns the correct hash, but `this.$scrollTo()` says that it can't find any object with that ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply used a `vue-router` navigation guard:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: "history",
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes,

    scrollBehavior (to, from, savedPosition) {
        if (to.hash) {
            this.app.$scrollTo(to.hash, 700);
            return { selector: to.hash }
        } else if (savedPosition) {
            return savedPosition;
        } else {
            //When the route changes, the page should scroll back to the top.
            this.app.$scrollTo('#app', 700);
            return { x: 0, y: 0 }
        }
    }
});

router.afterEach((to, from) => {
    if (to.hash && to.path != from.path)
        Vue.nextTick().then(() => VueScrollTo.scrollTo(to.hash, 700));
});
```

#### Unrelated to the question, but related to the navigation with hashes:

If you are publishing your website in `GitHub Pages`, you'll need to add these next two parts.

Add a 404.html static page, to redirect the navigation back to the root page, but passing a few parameters in the `sessionStorage`:

```
<script>
    const segment = 1;  
    //Gets the relative path and the hash of the URL.  
    sessionStorage.redirect = '/' + location.pathname.slice(1).split('/').slice(segment).join('/');  
    sessionStorage.hash = location.hash;  

    //Forces the navigation back to the main page, since it's the only entry point that works.
    location.replace(location.pathname.split('/').slice(0, 1 + segment).join('/'));
</script>
```

Alter your `main.js` page to expect the redirect parameters:

```
new Vue({
    router,
    i18n,
    render: (h) => h(App),
    created() {
        //If a redirect exists, tell the router.
        if (sessionStorage.redirect) {
            const redirect = sessionStorage.redirect;
            const hash = sessionStorage.hash;
            delete sessionStorage.redirect;
            delete sessionStorage.hash;

            this.$router.push(redirect + hash);
        }
    }
}).$mount("#app");
```