# How to include hashtag in Symfony routing

Tags: symfony, routes, symfony-routing

I need to create routing like

```
http://localhost:89/app_dev.php/list#gold-coin
```

So it will open specific tab on navigation.

But my routing not working as expected.

```
shop_product:
    path: /list#{slug}
    methods: [GET]
```

Edit:

I have three tabs tab-A, tab-B, tab-C and I need to display list of products related to tab-A on clicking url:  `http://localhost:89/app_dev.php/list#tab-A`. (consider tab-A as category). I need tab-A as a slug parameter and we are not preferring url like  `http://localhost:89/app_dev.php/list/tab-A`

Comment: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-routing-improvements

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking for.  You can generate url's with fragments easy enough.  But are you trying to actually extract the slug and pass it onto your list controller?  That won't work.

Comment: @Cerad: edited question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-i-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url-on-my-server-side-application-php-ruby  Just not going to happen.

Answer (score 2):

The `#gold-coin` is not send to the server. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-i-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url-on-my-server-side-application-php-ruby) to know why.

If you want to know the slug server side and you want to have its anchor, use a route like this one : `/list/{slug}` and, in your javascript, [use location.href to change the anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13735912/anchor-jumping-by-using-javascript/13736194).

If you do not want to know the anchor on the server side, [use the `_fragment` parameter when displaying the url](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-routing-improvements).

Answer (score 1):

Support for anchors has been introduced in the v 3.2. For the routing component using the `fragment` variable :

```
$this->get('router')->generate('articles', ['_fragment' => 'comments']);
```

Will generate an url like: `/articles#comments`

For more information [view the announcement](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-routing-improvements).

Answer (score 0):

There is not much you can do with routing about this.

```
http://localhost:89/app_dev.php/list#gold-coin
```

Is the same as for the server:

```
http://localhost:89/app_dev.php/list
```

The `anchor` `#something` is just used client side I reckon