# How to go to an HTML anchor programatically in shiny?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I can add a link to an anchor in the ui with `a("Go to Results", href = '#anchor_box')` and have the user to click on it to go to this anchor.

But how to have the window 'sent to' `#anchor_box` programatically? For example when results are available at the end of an `observeEvent()` with a long running time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use javascript for that. There are several possibilities, one way would be to get the element and use `scrollIntoView()`, see [anchor jumping by using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13735912/anchor-jumping-by-using-javascript).

An easy way to use javascript in `shiny`, is `library(shinyjs)`.

You could insert the following to tell R to move the element in focus:

```
runjs('
      document.getElementById("anchor_box").scrollIntoView();
    ')
```

In order to know, when to do so, you could wrap it within a `observeEvent()`:

```
observeEvent(eventExpr = input$clck, handlerExpr = {...})
```

Downside would be that refreshing the page would not automatically "scroll up to the top".

**Reproducible example:**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(

  a("Go to Results", href = '#anchor_box'),
  actionButton("clck", "Move Programmatically!"),

  plotOutput("plot", height = 1300),  
  div(id = "anchor_box", "HERE"),
  useShinyjs(),

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(1)
  })

  observeEvent(eventExpr = input$clck, handlerExpr = {
    runjs('
      document.getElementById("anchor_box").scrollIntoView();
    ')
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```