# Show popup when <a href >link clicks

Tags: javascript, html

I just want to make a URL with a button when It clicks it must show a dialog with my message. Is there any way to achieve in HTML?. Already searched google, as a beginner I don't understand much. So a simple tutorial might help me.

the link should be like [www.google.com/webpage/#popup](http://www.google.com/webpage/#popup)

dialog must be shown in the center of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

`onClick` with a function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function AlertIt() {
  alert("ATTENTION! THIS IS AN ALERT");
}
</script>

<a href="javascript:AlertIt();">click me</a>
```

Complex single one-liner:

```
<a href="http://example.com/"
 onclick="return alert('Please click on OK to continue.');">click me</a>
```

Comment: I just want the link should be like this: www.google.com/popup .. how to make that

Comment: is there any way to convert like www.example.com/#dialog

Comment: Then edit the href attribute according to the second example

Comment: but this alert should be shown on the top. isn't it? I want to show it to the center of the screen

Comment: Alerts are browser-specific, so when you want a cross-browser-consistent custom alert, you have to use either a library, or use a styled element of your webpage. You can take a look at [SweetAlert](https://sweetalert.js.org/), that might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a [`hashchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/hashchange_event)-event!
Make a check-hash function and call it initially, so that loading the URL with the hash has the same behavior as changing the hash when already on-page.

You could create an array holding the IDs of the elements that should "listen" for such a `hashchange`, and give them a specific class (e.g. `.hash-selected`) when their ID equals the hash.

```js
const hashes = ["#popup"]; // List of IDs that are "listening"
let lastHash = "";
function checkHash() {
  if (hashes.includes(lastHash)) // Remove class from last selected element
    document.querySelector(lastHash).classList.remove("hash-selected");
  if (hashes.includes(location.hash)) // Add class to current selected element
    document.querySelector(location.hash).classList.add("hash-selected");
  
  // Save current hash as 'lastHash' for first if-statement when calling 'checkHash()' again
  lastHash = location.hash;
}

checkHash(); // Initial function-call for same behavior on "page-open"
window.addEventListener("hashchange", () => checkHash());
```

```css
body {margin: 0}
#popup {
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  background: lightgreen;
}
#popup.hash-selected {transform: translateY(0)}
```

```html
<div id="popup">
  <p>Some sample text</p>
  <a href="#">Close</a>
</div>
<a href="#popup">Open popup</a>
```

We could even easily fill the `hashes`-array with IDs of elements that have a specific class, like `.hash-listen`:

```
const hashes = [];
for (let el of document.querySelectorAll(".hash-listen"))
  hashes.push("#" + el.id);

// ...
```

**Sidenote**
To remove hashchanges from the browser-history, you should take a look at this answer that [demonstrates the `history.replaceState()`-function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13736194/13561410).

Answer (score -1):

```html
    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/" onclick="myAlert()">Click Here</a>

    <script>
        function myAlert() {
            alert('hello there!');
        }
    </script>
```