# Failure to scroll when opening a link to a block

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a link that goes https://test.com/#testblock1

When I open this link via "target:_blank", I have #testblock1 open right away, and then it goes up sharply. What is the best way to override scrolling up?

Tried different options already, but I don't even understand a little bit how to google it correctly. The only options are to disable scrolling completely.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: [look at this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13735912/anchor-jumping-by-using-javascript)

Comment: Perhaps this will make it easier to understand. For example here is a site where I open it in a new window by following a link: https://planeandotuexito.com.mx/#contacto - it immediately opens as necessary, but after a second it throws me back up again.